# Shopware 6.5 - update from 6.4 using symfony flex

Tags: shopware6, symfony-flex

I have installed Shopware 6.4.20.0 in my local dev environment using Shopware's new symfony-flex template. Now I want to update my local version to Shopware 6.5.

What is the best way to update my local installation to 6.5, from the commandline and using composer?

Running `composer update` alone doesn't do the trick, as the shopware/* packages in my composer.json are tight to 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following packages to `~6.5.0` under the `require` part of your `composer.json`

- `shopware/core`
- `shopware/storefront`
- `shopware/administration`
- `shopware/elasticsearch`

Also under `require` remove `shopware/recovery`.

Then run `composer update` again. It may still complain that some packages can't be resolved due to version conflicts. Either try adding `--with-all-dependencies` to the command or if that doesn't work manually change the version to the newly required in the `require-dev` part. This would likely be the `symfony/*` packages that need to be changed to `~6.2.0`. Then run the update command again until all the version constraints have been satisfied.

Afterwards run `composer recipes:update`, followed by `bin/console system:update:finish` to execute the database migrations.

Comment: Thx @dneustadt, can you please add whether I need to run `composer recipes:update` for the shopware bundles?

Comment: Yes you should but make sure to backup `.env` and custom `*.yml` config file if you have them. Just in case.

Comment: @dneustadt What about using in the pipeline? Do we need to add the receipes:update command in the pipeline too? I updated my production template to symfony flex, but after deployment the shop gives 500 error. Cannot access the admin or storefront.